# Load image from project in react chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a react chrome extension. I started off with the simple project found [here](https://github.com/upmostly/react-chrome-extension). In its structure, the popup is contained in Modal.js and I would like to include an image in it which is contained in the project. However, to access that I must use `chrome.runtime.getURL("image_file.png")`, which I cannot access in Modal.js, but only in content.js. How should I get the image properly to Modal.js?

This is all activated when the browser action button is pressed, which calls this function within content.js:

```
function main() {
  const extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id
  if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html'))
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((html) => {
        const styleStashHTML = html.replace(
          /\/static\//g,
          `${extensionOrigin}/static/`
        )
        $(styleStashHTML).appendTo('body')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error)
      })
  }
}
```

The content of `index.html` is:

```
<div id="modal-window"></div>
```

but when the html is returned from the fetch it has expanded in the build to:

```
<div id="modal-window"></div><script src="/static/js/runtime-main.0d1674f1.js"></script><script src="/static/js/2.021a85b4.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.d80831e3.chunk.js"></script>
```

It is unclear to me how index.js is getting called but it is, which finds the div in index.html and replaces it with the modal object as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Modal from './Components/Modal'

ReactDOM.render(<Modal />, document.getElementById('modal-window'))
```

My current implementation of modal.js is as follows. Obviously the img src won't work as it is right now (needing to use chrome.runtime.getURL):

```
import React from 'react'

const Modal = () => {
  return <img src="icon48.png" alt="icon48"></img>
}

export default Modal
```

How would I actually be able to get the image src from chrome.runtime.getURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. I don't know if this is the best solution, but it is working for me.

Since I need to access `chrome.runtime.getURL` I need to do that from the content script. But I need the value of that in my component which doesn't have access to the chrome api. So I message between them through window events. Here is some example code:

ExampleComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let imgSrc = 'file.png'

// Note that this listener is outside the Component
window.addEventListener('ToComponent', (msg) => {
  imgSrc = msg.detail
})

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Note that this is occurring inside the Component constructor
    var event = new CustomEvent('FromComponent')
    window.dispatchEvent(event)

    this.state = {
      imgSrc: imgSrc,
      // etc.
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <img src={this.state.imgSrc} alt=""></img>
    )
  }
}
```

content.js:

```
window.addEventListener('FromComponent', () => {
  const imgSrc = chrome.runtime.getURL('file.png')

  // Send response
  var event = new CustomEvent('ToComponent', { detail: imgSrc })
  window.dispatchEvent(event)
})
```

Comment: seems like a nice solution, but there's got a to be a easier way, right?

Answer (score 1):

Content scripts can use chrome.runtime.getUrl().

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/

You'll need to declare the images in your manifest.json file using web_accessable_resources.

For example, mine are all copied to a img folder:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
{
  "resources": ["/img/*"],
  "matches": ["https://*"]
}
```

if using webpack, you'll need to copy them to your build as well:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  patterns: [
    {
      from:  'src/assets/img',
      to:    'img',
      force: true,
    },
  ],
}),
```

Then in the component call getUrl and include it in render's return:

```
const logo = chrome.runtime.getURL('img/logo.png');

return ( <img src={ logo } className="app-logo" alt="logo" /> );
```